# Create multiple jmeter.log files

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Jmeter for performance testing and running our tests via Jenkins build server.

We have Jmeter installed on our jenkins box and I am using an Ant build file to launch the jmx file and create the jtl report; which is then evaluated via the Performance plugin in Jenkins.

My problem is that we only have one instance of Jmeter and as such it only creates one jmeter.log file in the /bin directory.

As we will have multiple jobs calling the one Jmeter installation I don't want it, potentially, writing to the same log.

Is there a way of specifying multiple jmeter.log files per plan/job or amending the location?

Comment: Have you checked the -j Option? (https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

Comment: @Roscoe, why not make a real answer instead of comment ? your answer is good

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your suggestions.  Using a Jmeter Ant Task and have managed to place the log file into the workspace of the jenkins job by the following:

jmeterlogfile="${basedir}/jmeter.log"

This sits within the JMeter tags within the build file.

Comment: Note that the jmeterlogfile attribute is an attribute of the jmeter ant task rather than a jmeter property.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing .properties file, running jmeter from Windows cmd, simply navigate to bin folder and pass the argument -j[yourLogFileName.log], if you want log entries in a different log file.

C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin>jmeter.bat **-j myLog.log**